# Closing my DISLIN widget causes my whole program to close

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, plot

I am using [DISLIN](http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/)  to make some plots in a VC++ project. My dialog window contains a button that creates a DISLIN widget when pushed. Everything works great, but when I go to close the dislin widget it closes my whole program. I have tried both

```
g.swgopt("QUIT","CLOSE");
```

and

```
g.swgopt("OK","CLOSE");
```

upon widget creation, but they still both close my main application when "QUIT" is clicked, or when I close the widget with the 'x' at the top of the Windows window.

Here's the code that calls the creation of the widget from my main dialog window.

```
void CEx3Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    Dislin g;
    g.dislin_expsymbols = GetSelectedSymbols();
    try{
        widget();
    }catch(...){}
}
```

Here's an image of the widget.
[image: Widget appearance].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an OK button, not a quit button, cancel out the Quit and add an OK:

```
//g.wgquit (ip_l);
g.wgok(1);
g.wgfin();
```